# Unable to understand this Bag of words implementation

Tags: machine-learning, python, natural-language, text-mining

I am working on a chatbot project 

**Input Text format** 
List of the list in below sequence for multiple categories.

> [text from user, category of text, reply by chatbot]

`[['Hello', 'Greetings', 'Hello. I am Dexter. I will serve your leave inquiries.'],                             ['thank you', 'Closing', "It's glad to know that I have been helpful. Have a good day!"]]`

After all the text preprocessing steps, bag of words is implemented to be used in **nltk.classifier()** 
Below is how **BOW** is implemented using below function

```
def word_feats(words):
  return dict([(word, True) for word in words])
```

**For Example**

```
word_feats(extract_feature("This is very bad performance 20/5 in 10 over5s during to Virat 10kohli's can't you"))
```

**Output** 
`{'bad': True, 'perform': True, 'virat': True}`

I am not able to understand why **True** is embedded with each word in this Bag of word implementation. I am only aware of the numerical implementation of BOW. 
Could you please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: It's ver hard to guess, can you include sources on this particular usage?

Comment: This is just about understanding how the code works. The answer hinges on what the output of `extract_feature` is.